# MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

I have cloned a git repository containing a Vue project locally using `git clone`.
I then ran `npm install` to install the dependencies and got the `node_modules` folder.

On running `npm run serve` I get the following error:

```
[11920:03BEA178]   321556 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 429.1 (464.7) -> 429.1 (464.7) MB, 37.7 / 17.8 ms  (average mu = 0.980, current mu = 0.932) allocation failure
[11920:03BEA178]   321643 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 429.7 (465.2) -> 429.7 (465.2) MB, 61.2 / 0.9 ms  (average mu = 0.980, current mu = 0.932) allocation failure
[11920:03BEA178]   321765 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 432.2 (467.3) -> 432.2 (467.3) MB, 22.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.980, current mu = 0.932) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! vue-argon-dashboard-pro@1.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve --open`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-argon-dashboard-pro@1.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sagar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-10T09_32_00_595Z-debug.log
```

Also, my `node_modules` folder is about 8GB in size. I'm running this on a convertible with 2GB RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I managed to get past this error was by turning off minimization for TerserPlugin in `webpack.config.js` as follows:

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
optimization: {
    minimize: false,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
  },
};
```

This might not work for everyone as, in my opinion, this error occurs when the RAM isn't sufficient. I didn't have to set `minimize` to `false` when I ran the app on a laptop with 4GB RAM with much more hard disk space. You can set `minimize` to `false` in the development stage and set it back to `true` when the app is production ready.